# Is it possible to query by the following conditions in a query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a use case is to select flight route from MongoDB

However I need to split the search tasks into N queries

`FlightRoute.find({{"_id":{"airline":"Scoot","from":"KHH","to":"KIX"}})` and so on.

However, it is also impossible to do the following query with REGEX like syntax. Because it will involves other unrelated data

`FlightRoute.find({{"_id":{"airline":/Scoot, Tiger, Peach/,"from":"KHH","to":/KIX, NRT/}})`

Any good solution to do so?

```
[{"_id":{"airline":"Scoot","from":"KHH","to":"KIX"}},
 {"_id":{"airline":"Tiger","from":"KHH","to":"NRT"}},
 ...
 {"_id":{"airline":"Peach","from":"KHH","to":"KIX"}}]
```

Comment: Why would it not be possible? What have you tried? What result do you expect that you are not getting? That would not be a valid search for possible alternates as a regex, but there should be nothing stopping you using a valid regex.

Comment: you should take a look on the comment of the anwser.

Comment: Who are you talking to? I don't see you tagging anyone in the comment, just happened to see it as I wrote. Most people can read here. We ask questions of you because your content and comments are unclear. That means please take the time to address what you mean as asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
FlightRoute.find({
     '_id.airline': {$in: ['Scoot', 'Tiger', 'Peach']},
     '_id.from':'KHH',
     '_id.to': {$in: ['KIX', 'NRT']} });
```

Result

```
{ "_id" : { "airline" : "Scoot", "from" : "KHH", "to" : "KIX" } }
{ "_id" : { "airline" : "Tiger", "from" : "KHH", "to" : "NRT" } }
{ "_id" : { "airline" : "Peach", "from" : "KHH", "to" : "KIX" } }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But  some cases won't fit my expectation in your solution, eg. Scoot, KHH, NRT is not I want. But it could be found, right ?